# Как изменить размеры кнопок в GridLayout пропорционально размеру экрана телефона?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Имеется вертикальный `GridLayout` с четырьмя кнопками. На экранах устройств с разрешениями 1080x1920 и 720x1280 все отображается нормально. Но если запустить приложение на устройстве с разрешением, например, 480x800, то эти кнопки будут слишком огромными. Можно ли как-то программно изменять размеры кнопок и текста в них, в зависимости от размеров экрана?

xml-разметка:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:text="@string/text1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button2"
        android:text="@string/text2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button2"
        android:text="@string/text4"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button1"
        android:text="@string/text3"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Почитайте про dimens и квантификаторы https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861248/13483092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перестаньте задавать размеры ваших кнопок хардкодом. Т.е. вы должны максимально избегать ситуаций когда вы жестко фиксируете размер ваших кнопок.

В вашем LinearLayout вы можете задать размер кнопки 0dp и выставить ей весы `android:layout_weight` например вы можете каждой кнопке задать одинаковый вес (1) и они все будут равны и растянуться по всей ширине экрана (исключая отступы margins). Или же вы можете задать например им вес 20, 30, 50 и тогда первая кнопка будет занимать 20% экрана, вторая и третья соответственно 30% и 50%.

Не совсем понятно почему